# Why pyenv states that a version is not installed despite it does exist?

Tags: python, linux, pyenv

I have the error in the script output

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Python/Exec[set-python-global]/returns: pyenv: version `2.7.9' not installed
Error: /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv global 2.7.9 returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

However, the command

```
pyenv versions
```

returns correctly:

```
pyenv versions 
•   system (set by /usr/local/pyenv/version)
2.7.9
```

Some other commands:

```
sudo /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv global 2.7.9
pyenv: version `2.7.9' not installed
```

In the directory

```
/usr/local/pyenv/versions
```

I see the directory 2.7.9

The command

```
sudo /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv local 2.7.9
```

Also returns

```
pyenv: version `2.7.9' not installed
```

I am on RHEL 7

Answer (score 1):

`pyenv` installs Python into `$PYENV_ROOT`, defaults to `$HOME/.pyenv`, for each user.

When you're using `sudo`, you switch to `root` user temporarily in this very command. There's no python installed by `pyenv` for user `root` under directory `/root/.pyenv`. So python version `2.7.9` was not found.